# Jquery Calculator failing to load

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use a calculator in my asp .net web page. I am using keith woods plugin(http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html). I Have uploaded calculator jquery to root. but it just won't load.

But,all Other plugins like the jquery datepicker works fine.

This is the simpler version of the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.calculator.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.calculator.js"></script>

<script>  
$(function () {
    $("[id$=defaultCalc]").calculator();
}
</script>

   <asp:textbox id="defaultCalc" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

the webpage is not attached to any master page. and I have tried changing the selectors but nothing worked.

Comment: do you get any error in browser console ?

Comment: Open developer tool in your browser and check it there are any error in console tab. if yes please post it

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery version is too old. This code works. Note that the version 2.2.4 is randomly chosen.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/jquery.calculator.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.calculator.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= defaultCalc.ClientID %>").calculator();
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="defaultCalc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: It still does not work, i just put the same code in a new file and tried running it. also tried updating to jquery-3.2.1. It doesnt work for me. i am able to find what is causing this. But i found something new in the HTML page..a hidden viewstate class gets added to the page and it's updating the element...does this cause any issue? but then disabling view-state also did not help

Comment: This is the mark up - 
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="yLfp5/4gUolHBnxe/r1D8Ye+L5ba5nMB/Zl/21/9oHfN4A0NFrKN9309l9g1EL2FdCEEUUYkhpO3XnOygprp7BUYovT9O1OYwU+t9lMJtHk=" type="hidden">
</div>
<div>
<input name="defaultCalc" id="defaultCalc" type="text">
</div>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="0CDD4CA2" type="hidden">
 <input name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="P9PHYT8fQ4CXq6syxnVcvJWLgiMnvK/a+NOAL6Ho2wkroQhJBQsxVD/r7rtLJIy2o" type="hidden">
</div>

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. Check your browser console for errors and make sure the js files are in the correct folder etc.